# How to get ffmpeg to copy lyrics from flac to mp3?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, metadata, flac

Using ffmpeg 4.2.1, Windows 10 64-bit, at the command line to convert.

I am also using Tag&Rename and iTunes to set and view any ID3 tags.

Here is the ffmpeg command I am using: `ffmpeg -i input.flac -c:v copy -b:a 320k output.mp3`

When I get metadata information of the FLAC file (using `ffmpeg -i input.flac`), there is a `lyrics-eng` metadata field, containing the lyrics.

When I convert to an MP3 using ffmpeg, and then I retrieve the metadata information (using `ffmpeg -i input.mp3`), there is a `lyrics` metadata field, which contains the lyrics, but alas, those lyrics do not appear in Tag&Rename or iTunes.

I've also used other ffmpeg commands, such as `ffmpeg -i input.flac -ab 320k -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 output.mp3`, but no luck either.

Of course, if I manually copy & paste the lyrics from the FLAC to MP3, using Tag&Rename, the lyrics appear even in iTunes.  And retrieving the metadata using ffmpeg, the `lyrics-eng` metadata field appears, along with the `lyrics` metadata field.

I'm guessing `lyrics-eng` is Lyrics3 metadata and `lyrics` is USLT.

I want to be able to write to this mysterious `lyrics-eng` metadata field via command line.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show the full log from your first command.

Comment: @llogan Here is the link to the full log.  I used the ```-report``` switch for ffmpeg.  [https://www.dropbox.com/s/bt6rcexkok5tb2y/ffmpeg-20191218-102937.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bt6rcexkok5tb2y/ffmpeg-20191218-102937.log)

Comment: Does `-id3v2_version 3` or `-id3v2_version 4` alone, without `-map_metadata` work? Do you have a sample input file that you can share? What does ffmpeg show for the file that does show lyrics in iTunes?

Comment: @lloganI I performed both conversions as you suggested with the same results. I am also providing the full logs and the sample FLAC file.
```-id3v2_version 3```: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8n31z7pyz3kkg17/ffmpeg-20191220-085003_id3v2_version_3.log
```-id3v2_version 4```: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n1i11v1buxn6z9k/ffmpeg-20191220-085142_id3v2_version_4.log
```FLAC```: https://www.dropbox.com/s/itxpd089sgdeopd/03.%20Miracle%20%28%ED%99%98%EC%83%81%EC%86%8D%EC%9D%98%20%EA%B7%B8%EB%8C%80%29.flac
For the file that shows the lyrics, ffmpeg displays the lyrics under the ```LYRICS```field.